# I can not install node-libcurl module

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-modules, node-gyp, node-libcurl

I am trying to install node-libcurl module on Ubuntu. To install, I am using the following command:

`npm install node-libcurl --save`

But I am facing this problem:

> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/releases/download/v1.1.0/node_libcurl-v1.1.0-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-libcurl@1.1.0 and node@8.0.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/myfolder/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:308:16)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-42-generic
>
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/myfolder/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/myfolder/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node" "--module_name=node_libcurl" "--module_path=/home/myfolder/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd /home/myfolder/node_modules/node-libcurl
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-42-generic
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! node-libcurl@1.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-libcurl@1.1.0 install script.

Can anyone help with some solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to use libcurl instead of node's built-in http functionality?

Comment: Hello, @mscdex . I had to use libcurl because the server I am requesting is answering with malformed responses. As the other node modules treat this, I could not get the information I needed. The error was related with `content-length` and `transfer-encoding`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some time, I realized that the libcurl was not installed at the machine. I did not realize it before because the error messages does not mention that, so it was not clear.

I solved with:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

And:

```
npm install node-libcurl --build-from-source
```

Comment: You're the real MVP. Came from Ubuntu. Isn't this sort of the definition of a dependency? Where are the devs :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `yarn add node-libcurl@next`. It will work.

Comment: `npm i node-libcurl@next` also works